# How do I get Finder to remember the size and location of the window?

Tags: macos, finder

Why doesn't Finder remember the damn window size and location? I keep reading crap about holding down Option key while dragging but that doesn't work. It just reverts back to its microscopic size the next time i open it. It's useless and very tedious and it really aggravates me.

How do I make this thing thing stay the way I want it to? I don't mind playing around with system stuff or running scripts - so long as I only have to do it once only.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a simple way to do that.

First you have to open new finder windows (not in Tabs).

Before you click on a new finder window hold the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key (not the Option key).

Now you can resize that window or move it around and it will remember that next time you open it.

Comment: not working majove

Comment: @atilkan this post was made in 2015 !

Comment: Just tried this on Monterey and it works!!! This has been annoying me for some time!!!  Finally enough to bring me here.  Thank you @Ruskes!!!

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution like @Ruskes's answer which doesn't work for me.

1. Close all the existing windows.
2. Open a new window and move it to your preferred location, resize it if needed.
3. Press `Cmd` + `Alt` + `Esc` to launch the ***Force Quit*** window, select the `Finder` to relaunch it.
4. Open a new finder window, now it's in the last preferred location.

Test on my Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

I've found for windows that have shortcuts, e.g. cmd-shift-h, cmd-shift-c, cmd-shift-u, etc. or any other folder in the Go menu that you can set the size and position by:

1. Close all windows
2. Open the window you want and set it's size and position
3. Close the window

Now each time you use the shortcut the window will be to what you set.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a specific solution to Finder's lack of ability to remember its size and position. What's more, it seems to have been inspired by this exact question.

[FinderFix](https://synappser.github.io/apps/finderfix/) Gives extra powers to your Finder windows!

> If after all those years of using your Mac you are still fighting with
> Finder to get it to behave as you wish, look no further, FinderFix
> will get it to open every new window in the exact same position and
> size you want it to.

I tried it, and it works as advertised. It also comes with some of the essential features of TotalFinder such as the option to open all windows in tabbed mode or activating Cut & Paste with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, without compromising the System Integrity Protection (SIP).

[image: FinderFix Preferences]