# How to set default finder window size?

Tags: macos, finder, defaults

How do I set the default size of my finder window to a size of my choice? Currently each time I open a finder window, it opens up in a very small size and I have to adjust it before I can start looking for my files. I'm running Yosemite.

Answer (score 113):

It is very easy to do this:

1. Open a new Finder window.
2. As you resize the window, hold the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> (not <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd>) key. Close resized window.
3. Then hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd> key as you right click on Finder in the Dock and click *Relaunch*. Another way to implement this step is to press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd> / <kbd>Esc</kbd>, select Finder from the menu to pop-up and click on Relaunch.
4. Any Finder windows opened after this will open at that size.

**Note:** This does not work for windows opened from folders on the desktop.

Comment: Does not work when opening shared network drive.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: **Note:** After relaunching the finder window once, through the above method, the 3rd step is not required to open the finder again. The finder window opens with the size you specified, even after restarting the mac. *Tested on - mac version 10.13.6*

Comment: @tog22 : you're not holding it right.

Comment: @tog22 : Yeah, I second the "you're not holding it right" (except I'd add "maybe you're...").  I had to do it several times before noting, for example, that you have to let go of the button before you let go of the command key, and you have to let go of both the Alt and Ctrl keys (I didn't have a right-clickable mouse) before you choose "relaunch".  This would have been much easier as an actual option to choose, instead of this dumb click-drag gymnastics.

Comment: This worked, but after opening a file from airdrop, it got tiny again.

Comment: Works on macOS Big Sur

Comment: Perfect solution! Wonder how you discovered it :-)

Comment: Great answer. Under Monterey, I didn't even need to do step 3. Normally opening a new Finder window was in the size I set.

Answer (score 41):

This works for me in MacOS Catalina, Monterey (in 2022) and Ventura (in 2023):

1. Open a new Finder window, do not navigate to any folders yet;
2. Resize the window to the size you want *(however don't move the window to your desired location yet)*;
3. To lock the location and size:
4. start by pressing the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> **and** <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd> keys together **and** drag the window to your desired location;
5. release your mouse button first then release the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> AND <kbd>Alt</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd> keys second;
6. Close resized window;
7. Any Finder windows opened after this will open at that size.

Comment: This works, unlike the top answer. I feel like my chest is free from a really tight fitting jacket now.

Comment: This does not seem to work on MacOS 12.5 Monterey.

Comment: Note, when you open a finder window, do *not* navigate to any other folders. you need to all the adjustment on the folder that opens. You cannot navigate to a particular folder. Confirmed this works on MacOS Ventura 13.2.

Comment: @todd412, not sure what problems you had but it worked for me last year when I upgraded to Monterey, and now to Ventura as confirmed by technogeek1995

Comment: Strange, this no longer works on `10.15.7 (19H2026)`

Answer (score 13):

Open a finder window, hold down the option key and resize the window as you wish. Close all finder windows and next time you open a new one it will remember the size.

Comment: This is what worked for me.

Comment: Option is disabling snapping for me.

Comment: This also worked for me on Big Sur. Both launching Finder via icon and `open .` from Terminal too!

Comment: It works but it's only temporary, it doesn't set it as default. If you relaunch the finder or reboot it loses the setting. So in fact it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Open a folder in list or cover flow view. Then press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Now hold <kbd>option</kbd> key and press `Return to default` button at the bottom. New finder windows will be opened normally.
You can try deleting `.DS_Store` file in folders with false view.

You can also delete the normally hidden .DS_Store file with some utilities or with the terminal app and a command line removal - since Finder will recreate this file when it's missing, it's pretty safe to delete them.

```
 rm .DS_Store
```

You need to get to the directory so you can type `cd` and then drag in the folder that needs clearing. (Navigate one folder up in path view or using the title bar of the finder window) and drag the folder in to the terminal window after you type `cd` and <kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: Yes, it requires setting to list view. Can't do with column view. I had to do more steps than this answer describes. But I eventually got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Previous solutions seem to have stopped working with recent macOS releases. Yesterday, I answered a very [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171271/how-do-i-get-finder-to-remember-the-size-and-location-of-the-window) related to both size and position of Finder windows. I am reflecting it here for completeness.

There's now a specific solution to Finder's lack of ability to remember its size and position. What's more, it seems to have been [inspired by this exact question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171271/how-do-i-get-finder-to-remember-the-size-and-location-of-the-window).

[FinderFix](https://synappser.github.io/apps/finderfix/) Give extra powers to your Finder windows!

> If after all those years of using your Mac you are still fighting with
> Finder to get it to behave as you wish, look no further, FinderFix
> will get it to open every new window in the exact same position and
> size you want it to.

I tried it, and it works as advertised. It also comes with some of the essential features of TotalFinder such as the option of opening all windows in tabbed mode or activating Cut & Paste with `Cmd`+`X` / `Cmd`+`V`, without compromising the System Integrity Protection (SIP).

[image: FinderFix Preferences]

Comment: Thanks - this is the only fix I've seen that works when opening finder windows from the Desktop

Answer (score 0):

#### Applescript

For the desperate, here is something you could run as a cron job:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set everyWindow to every Finder window
    repeat with currentWindow in everyWindow
        set bounds of currentWindow to {100, 100, 1200, 750} -- Adjust the dimensions as needed
    end repeat
end tell
```