# How to set default Finder window size for *all* situations?

Tags: macos, finder

There are tons of  posts about that (like [How to set default finder window size?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175883/how-to-set-default-finder-window-size)), but none are able to change the default size *everywhere*, including **shared network folders** from a Windows PC.

So when I open a network folder through **Finder / Connect to Server** with a smb:// address, the opened Finder size is **always very small** (around 770x440 px), regardless of the "remembered" size I did with the Cmd+Resize+Relaunch trick I see everywhere.

I am on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), but it never worked in past OS X versions either.

Answer (score 6):

I search a lot in `com.apple.finder.plist` file (under the folder `~/Library/Preferences`) to found the answer but I can't.
I think the best option to do what you want is to create an AppleScript and use it as a service with automator.

I know that is not what you want, but it's a solution to change window's size for the active window with a shortcut.

We will use the Applescript below (more about this Applescript [here](http://www.mactips.info/2011/10/size-windows-correctly-with-an-easy-applescript))

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set bounds of front window to {0, 100, 490, 248}
    end tell
end run
```

### How to create the Service with Automator

1. Open Automator and Select Service

   [image]
2. Search for `AppleScript` and double click on `Run AppleScript`
3. In `Service Receives` set to `no input` in `any application`
4. Copy the Script below and paste it in Automator
   [image]
5. Don't forget to save your service (cmd+s)
   [image]

### Assign a shortcut for your service

1. Go to System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts
2. From the left sidebar select Services
3. Find your service and add a shortcut (e.x. cmd+shift+w)
   [image]

Now open your folder, press `cmd+shift+w` and the window's bounds will be change to `{0, 100, 490, 248}`

More Informations about BoundsProperty, to create your own [here](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/11.html)

---

### Update:

Here's the AppleScript to **choose your own width and height for the window without changing the destination from the side of the screen**. Just change `myWindowWidth` and `myWindowHeight`. Also I have some other variables in comment to understand the code. Please reply if you have any question!

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        --we take the bounds properties of the front window
        set windowAreaDimensions to bounds of the front window
        set x1 to item 1 of windowAreaDimensions
        set y1 to item 2 of windowAreaDimensions
        set x2 to item 3 of windowAreaDimensions
        set y2 to item 4 of windowAreaDimensions

        set destToLeft to x1
        set destToTop to y1
        --set destToRight to x2
        --set destToBottom to y2
        --set previousWindowWidth to destToRight - destToLeft
        --set peviousWindowHeight to destToBottom - destToTop

        set myWindowWidth to 730
        set myWindowHeight to 521
        set sameWidth to destToLeft + myWindowWidth
        set sameHeight to destToTop + myWindowHeight

        --The following line script return the bounds of the front window
        --get the bounds of the front window

        --The following line set our bounds for the front window
        set bounds of front window to {destToLeft, destToTop, sameWidth, sameHeight}
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Is there a way not to change the (x, y) coordinates? Or to retrieve the current ones to reapply them? Because it's a bit annoying when you have multiple monitors, as the window always move to the same screen, regardless of which screen it was before.

Comment: @dbernard Of course! I update my answer with new AppleScript. Just change myWindowWidth and myWindowHeight properties.

Comment: @dbernard I'm happy for that! If you have others questions comment below or if I solved your problem please accept my answer!