# Set default Finder window size

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

What's the recommended way to set the default size of a Finder window in macOS Mojave? I've tried following advice like that given in [How to set default finder window size?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175883/how-to-set-default-finder-window-size), but no luck. It's annoying how hard Apple make this, but even if I could edit a plist file, that would be sufficient for now...

Answer (score 3):

So, it seems a year later, nobody had been able to solve this one, (couldn't find any solutions posted **any** website) so I decided to give it a shot. After some extensive research, I've arrived at the following solution.

**macOS Version:** This was tested on macOS 11.0 **Big Sur** and on macOS 10.15 **Catalina** as well

### Customizing the default dimensions of the Finder window

1. Open the Terminal application, enable the "Quit Finder" menu item

   ```sh
   defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool true; killall Finder
   ```
2. In Finder, open a new window and configure its size/dimensions to the exact way you like it
3. Quit the Finder application (**⌘ Q**)
4. Launch the Finder application

   - When you first open the Finder application, **a window is not created**, which is a bit unintuitive `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`
5. In Finder, create a new window (**⌘ N**)

   - The position/dimensions of this window *should* be exactly the way you like it. Finder determined what the position/dimension ought to be using configurations stored in the `~/.DS_Store` file. Every time a Finder window is moved or resized, the `~/.DS_Store` file will be written to.

Any future windows *should* default to opening with this size/position on the screen.

**Note:** If you try to open a Finder window on a larger screen, don't expect the window to be centered. Finder doesn't store the relative offset of the window to the screen, it stores the X/Y pixel offset from the top-left corner

**Note:** Don't try and be clever by removing write access to `~/.DS_Store`, it didn't work out for me. Finder's reaction to losing write access is to ignore the `~/.DS_Store` file completely, causing every new window to open with the factory-default window configurations

Comment: I think this will only work for Finder windows that you open in the default location. For instance, as a test, if you run in Terminal `mkdir test && open test`, I expect Finder will revert back to its stock size. There isn't really a way to do what you're asking (unless a developer can find the private functions used so they can be overridden in SIMBL, or some such.)

Comment: If it worked @Noldorin don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)