# Set default Finder window size when opening directory from Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, folders

I'm wondering if there is a solution to opening a directory from Terminal so that it opens with my preferred saved window size. It never works when I'm opening a folder for the first time using Terminal, although if I use `open .`, then resize the window, and then do `open .` again, it will open to the desired size.

I have followed the steps in the following two posts

- [How to set default finder window size?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175883/how-to-set-default-finder-window-size/192959#192959)
- [Set default Finder window size](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353801/set-default-finder-window-size)

And I've also tried running `find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete` to ensure my preferred view options are applied to all folders I open, but I am not sure if that applies directly to the window size.

These steps work when I'm opening Finder from the dock, but it seems like changing the window size does not work or apply when I am opening a directory from Terminal for the first time (using `open .` or `open subdir/`). I'm very irritated by the large and wide window that it opens with in Big Sur (running 11.0.1). I just did a clean install of the OS, deleting my data as well, and I don't recall the Finder window being this wide automatically in any previous versions of macOS.

Is there any solution to this? Could the fact that I did a clean install when upgrading to Big Sur have anything to do with why my Finder window is so wide?

Comment: I just downgraded to Catalina (and the default window size is no longer unnecessarily wide), but I still experience the same problem in Terminal from Catalina. Will leave this question up for now in case it will be helpful to others in the future.