How to permanently change the finder window size?
How do I permanently change the Finder window size?

There are lots of answers here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175883/how-to-set-default-finder-window-size

To change the Finder window size:

Open a new Finder window using the Finder icon in the Dock(make sure
all other Finder windows are closed).
Hold Command and Option/Alt simultaneously and resize/reposition your window however you like.
Close the window.
Repeat steps 1-3 but instead of clicking the Finder icon in the dock, open any folder on your Desktop.

Tested on macOS 15 Beta(24A5298h)
